# Simple C++ password program

Tags: c++, passwords, codeblocks

I'm learning to use C++ and I decided to create a password program where the user is asked for the password and it compares the user input to the password and returns a wrong or a right. For some reason, this programs always returns a wrong and I'm not sure why. It must be something to do with comparing the strings but I'm not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string pass = "password";
    string input;
    cout << "What is your password: ";
    cin >> input;
    if (input==pass){
        cout << "Correct" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Wrong" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would love some help from programmers who are in any way more well versed in C++ as I've just transferred over to C++ from Python and the transitions a bit rocky.

Comment: [Works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d443e4db3d55cd3)

Comment: Does the password string in your actual code contain space characters?

Comment: This is the actual test code and I've made no changes in posting it here. And changing 'string pass = "password"' to 'string pass = "password\r"' has no effect.

Comment: Are you inputting the actual string `"password"` as a command line argument?

Comment: I'm inputting the string as: password (no quotes)

Comment: You should not use this program if you want to create a real password program. The password must be encrypted.

Comment: So it turns out my problem was that I'm using CodeBlocks and the IDE doesn't automatically build the program when you ask it to run the program. So I have to tell it to build then run it and this code actually works fine. My stupid mistake and I'm sorry if I confused people or asked a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

1.you could use compare function, to see:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

2.you should debug at line  if (input==pass){
to print pass and input and check if they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed to:

```
#include <string>
```

to get the definition of the insertion operator (for `cin >> input;`) and std::string::operator==() (for `if (input==pass)`).  Once I did that, it worked fine in Visual C++.

What compiler are you using?